# How to get names of all files in google drive using ios framework

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Not able to get list of all filenames created after a specified data in Google Drive directory:

```
query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
//query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";
//query.q = @"mimeType = 'image/png'";
query.q = @"modifiedDate > '20011-06-04T12:00:00'";
authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] in itWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive clientID:kClientID  clientSecret:kClientSecret keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName delegate:self
```

Comment: I was not able to retrieve files from entire google drive directory for a given search query

Comment: Nope, I am getting incomplete list. For a example query.q = @"mimeType = 'image/png'" returns images in root directory rather than entire google drive directory

Comment: By the way, were you able to login?

Comment: I was able to login to the Google drive account

Answer (score 2):

Changed the scope in method authButtonClicked of DrEditFilesListViewController.m

Replace this scope kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile with kGTLAuthScopeDrive as follow

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile
                                         clientID:kClientId
                                     clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                 keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                         delegate:self
                                 finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

to

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                         clientID:kClientId
                                     clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                 keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                         delegate:self
                                 finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your date:

```
query.q = @"modifiedDate > '20011-06-04T12:00:00'";
```

Do you want to use `2011-06-04`? If so, then:

```
query.q = @"modifiedDate > '2011-06-04T12:00:00'";
```